# sqlite query failing - no such column

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a db that is created like this...

```
public class DataBaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    Context mContext;
    private static final String TAG = "DataBaseManager";
    private static final int dbVersion = 1;// ++ for DB  changes

    static final String dbName ="LCInstore";
    //Table Names
    static final String allIcons = "Icons";
    static final String allScreens = "Screens";
    static final String isLookUp = "LookUp";

    //Column Names - LookUp
    static final String colIconID = "IconID";
    static final String colScreenID = "ScreenID";
    static final String colRank = "Rank"; // order

    //Column Names shared by tables: Screens and Icons
    static final String colID = "ID";
    static final String colType = "Type";
    static final String colName = "Name";

    //Column Names - Icons
    static final String colImage = "Image";
    static final String colLabel = "Label";
    static final String colIntent = "Intent";
    static final String colIParams = "Params";


    public DataBaseManager(Context context) {
        super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion); 
        mContext = context;
        Log.v(TAG, "Initaited");

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v(TAG, "on create called");

        // Create Icon Table if does not exist
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ allIcons +"" +
                "("+colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                    colName + " TEXT," +
                    colImage + " BLOB," +
                    colLabel + " TEXT," +
                    colIntent + " TEXT," +
                    colType + " TEXT)");

        // Create Screens Table if does not exist
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + allScreens +"" +
                 "("+colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                    colName + " TEXT," +
                    colType + " TEXT)");

        //Create LookUp Table if does not exist
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + isLookUp +"" +
                 "("+colIconID + " INTEGER, "+
                    colScreenID + " INTEGER," +
                    colRank + " INTEGER)");

         InsertInitData(db);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v(TAG, "on upgrade called");
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+allIcons);




    }


    private void InsertInitData(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //screens
        ContentValues cv2=new ContentValues();
            cv2.put(colName, "DR_Home");
            cv2.put(colType, "dr_home");
            db.insert(allScreens, colID, cv2);
            cv2.put(colName, "DR_Sub");
            cv2.put(colType, "dr_sub");
            db.insert(allScreens, colID, cv2);

            //all Icons
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

           cv.put(colName, "Icon1");
           cv.put(colImage, getBlobFromRes(R.drawable.dr_tablet_icon));
           cv.put(colLabel, "MY ICON 1");
           cv.put(colIntent, "someIntent");
           cv.put(colType, "generic");
           db.insert(allIcons, colID, cv);

           cv.put(colName, "Icon2");
           cv.put(colImage, getBlobFromRes(R.drawable.dr_tablet_icon));
           cv.put(colLabel, "MY ICON 2");
           cv.put(colIntent, "someIntent");
           cv.put(colType, "generic");
           db.insert(allIcons, colID, cv);

           cv.put(colName, "Icon3");
           cv.put(colImage, getBlobFromRes(R.drawable.dr_tablet_icon));
           cv.put(colLabel, "MY ICON 3");
           cv.put(colIntent, "someIntent");
           cv.put(colType, "generic");
           db.insert(allIcons, colID, cv);

           cv.put(colName, "Icon4");
           cv.put(colImage, getBlobFromRes(R.drawable.dr_tablet_icon));
           cv.put(colLabel, "MY ICON 4");
           cv.put(colIntent, "someIntent");
           cv.put(colType, "generic");
           db.insert(allIcons, colID, cv);

           cv.put(colName, "Icon5");
           cv.put(colImage, getBlobFromRes(R.drawable.dr_tablet_icon));
           cv.put(colLabel, "MY ICON 5");
           cv.put(colIntent, "someIntent");
           cv.put(colType, "generic");
           db.insert(allIcons, colID, cv);

           cv.put(colName, "Icon6");
           cv.put(colImage, getBlobFromRes(R.drawable.dr_tablet_icon));
           cv.put(colLabel, "MY ICON 6");
           cv.put(colIntent, "someIntent");
           cv.put(colType, "generic");
           db.insert(allIcons, colID, cv);

           cv.put(colName, "Icon7");
           cv.put(colImage, getBlobFromRes(R.drawable.dr_tablet_icon));
           cv.put(colLabel, "MY ICON 7");
           cv.put(colIntent, "someIntent");
           cv.put(colType, "generic");
           db.insert(allIcons, colID, cv);



        // icon screen lookups
        ContentValues cv3=new ContentValues();
            cv3.put(colIconID, 1);
            cv3.put(colScreenID, 2);
            cv3.put(colRank, 1);
            db.insert(isLookUp, colID, cv3);

            cv3.put(colIconID, 2);
            cv3.put(colScreenID, 2);
            cv3.put(colRank, 2);
            db.insert(isLookUp, colID, cv3);

            cv3.put(colIconID, 3);
            cv3.put(colScreenID, 2);
            cv3.put(colRank, 3);
            db.insert(isLookUp, colID, cv3);

            cv3.put(colIconID, 4);
            cv3.put(colScreenID, 2);
            cv3.put(colRank, 4);
            db.insert(isLookUp, colID, cv3);

            cv3.put(colIconID, 5);
            cv3.put(colScreenID, 2);
            cv3.put(colRank, 5);
            db.insert(isLookUp, colID, cv3);

            cv3.put(colIconID, 6);
            cv3.put(colScreenID, 2);
            cv3.put(colRank, 6);
            db.insert(isLookUp, colID, cv3);

            cv3.put(colIconID, 7);
            cv3.put(colScreenID, 2);
            cv3.put(colRank, 7);
            db.insert(isLookUp, colID, cv3);

    }
```

you'll notice that one table,  'allScreens' or "Screens" has one row that in the Name column i am putting "DR_Home"

i do a query later to find out the value of the ID column of that row using this method and passing `DR_Home`  to it:

```
public int getScreenID(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        int sID;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT "+colID+ " FROM " + allScreens + " WHERE " + colName + "=" +name;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        sID = c.getInt(0);
        c.close();
        return sID;
    }
```

should return the value of the ID column but i am getting an error:

```
03-22 06:34:35.830: E/AndroidRuntime(29864): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: DR_Home: , while compiling: select * from Screens WHERE Name=DR_Home
```

No such Column?  im not asking for a column called DR_Home  i am asking for the value of the ID column in the row where the Name column = DR_home..  at least thats what i thought.. i have messed up the syntax somewhere.. please help

Comment: You should put the name in quotes, so that the query says `Name='DR_HOME'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is wrong, as `WHERE column = string` will not work.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT "+colID+ " FROM " + allScreens + " WHERE " + colName + "=?";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] {name});
```

Use `?` which will be replaced by the second `rawQuery()` parameter. Strongly recommended.

Not recommended: `WHERE column = "string"`

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
String selectQuery = String.format("SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s = ?",
    colID, allScreens, colName);

Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{name});
```

Answer (score -1):

`name = DR_home` means "column name equals column `DR_home`. You probably want to quote it if you want to string search (which I surmise you do, but I haven't peeked your code in depth since it's too long):  `name = 'DR_Home'`.

Comment: Give me a break. There's no encouragement at all. This, and all other answers, yields a working solution for the poster. You, on the other hand, by issuing the same kind of -1 to everybody's answers except yours, encourages nothing but a sense of "I'm the best, everyone else suck".

If anything, that behaviour will stop people from answering questions because they know they will have an eagle eye on them, breaking their legs if they do the slightest error in trying to be helpful.

That itself is an even bigger disencouragement, if you ask me.

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong. I voted up the answer from @Waqas. So save it. The vote system is meant to differ between good and bad answers. You could have improved your answer and with a short `@WarrenFaith` notified me and I would have removed the down vote. Also there is no "slightest error" in your question. I gave the reason: You encourage to do it wrong. To the "working solution": I prefer a good solution so a working solution without the hint that it is still a bad solution and therefore I will vote it down. That's the freedom of my opinion and I "pay" with my reputation for that.

Answer (score -1):

Your query String is wrong

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT "+colID+ " FROM " + allScreens + " WHERE " + colName + " = '" +name + "'";
```

the name you give in where should be in single quotes

Answer (score -1):

Change your old query `"SELECT "+colID+ " FROM " + allScreens + " WHERE " + colName + "=" +name;` to

```
 "SELECT "+colID+ " FROM " + allScreens + " WHERE " + colName + "='" +name+"'";
```